# Instability in Newton's method for matrix inversion

Tags: matrices, newton-raphson

I'm playing around with matrix inversion schemes for my own edification.  I figured I would give [Newtons's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Newton.27s_method), which sure looks straightforward enough, a try.  My calculation is going unstable no matter what I do.  I am working in Matlab and doing straightforward matrix multiplies:

```
for i=1:its
    matinv = 2*matinv - matinv*mat*matinv
end
```

Am I doing something wrong, like, for instance, should I be updating one row/column at a time or something?  I haven't been able to find any details of that sort.  I know that a bad starting point can cause trouble, but I have started at so many points now that I think it must be something more fundamental.

Comment: From your link, what does this mean "A generalization of Newton's method as used for a multiplicative inverse algorithm may be convenient, if it is convenient to find a suitable starting seed? In other words, is there more too it than what you tried? Have you looked at the references and examples? Maybe you can find more details on page 201 of https://vintageapple.org/byte/pdf/198604_Byte_Magazine_Vol_11-04_Number_Crunching.pdf

Comment: @Moo   Thank you!  So it was all in finding a good starting point.  I had ruled that out because the method had failed with so many starting points, I thought it had to be something else!  Seems to work like a charm now!  Thanks again!